# What's the logic of this error?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

While declaring DATABASE_VERSION  I declared as int type.
But I'm getting an error that shows " cannot convert from string to int"  . Why should I declare version type as string and not int.
If I change it to string also I can't able to pass version type as an argument which is of int type.

Comment: At least post your code to help you.

Comment: error can happen possibly in this area `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1` maybe you declared as "1"

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

Use this code
or refer this Link [Click Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: it really helped..the reference you gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int CURRENT_DATABASE_VERSION_VALUE = 1;
```

you can do while for more strong check

step 1)==> to check the string is integer or not

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    }
    // only got here if we didn't return false
    return true;
}
```

step 2)==>

please do this to convert string to integer

```
int foo=0;
    if(isInteger("yours_current_value_tp_pass_to_check")){
    foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");}else{//show problem}
```